# Vertex/Edge/Face selection not showing

Tags: modeling

I have a friend who works on my team for a game project, but he's experiencing an issue I haven't seen before. He is unable to select the selection modes for vertex, edge and face selection, which can be toggled using the three buttons at the bottom panel of the 3D view.

This image shows his issue. The red circle shows where the buttons are supposed to be positioned.
[image]
These are the three buttons he's missing (Screenshot taken from my Blender)

[image]

I've already suggested CTRL+TAB while in Edit Mode, but this does not work for him.

As far as I know, he's using a default Blender setup (He have received instructions to not mess with the settings in Blender, part from the settings I have written down, such as unit size, export defaults, etc.)

Comment: Curves do not have that buttons. You edit it clicking in its vertices.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys. We found the solution, and as mentioned it was because the person who made the file did not convert the curves to a mesh, thus leading to the issue he had.